# Is it possible to have conditionals in hiera yaml?

Tags: puppet, hiera

I am trying to achieve following. - I have certain variables defined in hiera yaml for a.yaml - Some of the variables I want to read from the external facts. - However whenever an external fact is not defined I want to use some default.

So for example

```
---
key1: value1
key2: %{value2_from_facts} | value2
```

In this case if custom fact 'value2fromfacts' is not defined, I want key2 to have value2. Is this possible?

Is there any better alternative to having defaults assigned to hiera variable if the facts used are not resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Hiera offers a good way about this scenario. I recommend solving this on the manifest level, e.g.

```
if $factvalue {
  $myvalue = $factvalue
}
else {
  $myvalue = hiera('key2')
}
```

To modularize this, create a [parser function](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_functions.html) that should work like

```
my_hiera($factvalue,'key2')
```

with a body like

```
override = args.shift
if override.empty?
  # duplicate hiera()
  key, default, override = HieraPuppet.parse_args(args)
  HieraPuppet.lookup(key, default, self, override, :priority)
else
  override
end
```

This is utterly untested and should serve only as a sketch of the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Felix, but I wanted to avoid if/else, because I have quite lots of parameters.

Comment: I see...I shall add an alternative using a custom function.